# mongo aggregate with nested field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

My fields look like this

```
{
"_id" : 12345,
"_class" : "com.Location",
"locations" : [
    {
        "longitude" : -12345675433,
        "latitude" : 12345675433,
        "ts" : NumberLong("134546456"),
        "fullAddress" : "123456 road United States",
        "Phone" : "123456677",
        "Name" : "Upagna",
        "accuracy" : 0
    },
    {
        "longitude" : -12345675433,
        "latitude" : 12345675433,
        "ts" : NumberLong("134546456"),
        "fullAddress" : "123456 road United States",
        "Phone" : "123456677",
        "Name" : "Upagna",
        "accuracy" : 0
    },
```

The end result would be the id and number of locations for each id and the phone for each id. I was able to figure out the count of location, but couldnt add the phone to end result

```
db.locations.aggregate([{$project : {_id: 0, id: "$_id", total: {$size: "$locations", }}}])
```

The end reult should look like this

```
{ "id" : 36761, "total" : 2 ,"Phone" : "123456677" }
{ "id" : 36904, "total" : 8 ,"Phone" : "123456677"}
{ "id" : 36945, "total" : 7 ,"Phone" : "123456677"}
{ "id" : 37095, "total" : 1 ,"Phone" : "123456677"}
```

Any help would me appreciated ..

Thanks

Comment: Do you just need the phone from first location ? or all the phones from locations array ?

Comment: It would be unique . phone of first location is fine

Comment: Try `db.locations.aggregate([{$project : {total: {$size: "$locations"}, "Phone":{"$arrayElemAt":["$locations.Phone", 0]}}}])`